# Probability of receiving a correct packet of $N$ bits

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

When a packet is transmitted on a communications link, the probability that a bit in packet is received in error is $p$.

Assume that the packet has $N$ bits. Suppose the packet length is random i.e. $N$ is random and is geometrically distributed with parameter $q$ where $$\Pr(N = k) = q(1 − q)^{k−1},\quad k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$$

The packet has to be re-sent if any of the bits are incorrect.
Find the probability that the packet is received correctly.

---

My attempt:

Define $X = x$ bits are received correctly.
$$Pr(X = d) = (1-p)^d$$

I believe the question is asking for $Pr(X=d|N = n)$, where $d = n$. That is, given that the packet is of length $n$, what is the probability of getting all $n$ bits correct? And I need to find it for all $N = n$.

$$Pr(X=n|N = n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{Pr((X=i)\cap(N=i))}{Pr(N=i)}$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I don't have a joint pdf of $X$ and $N$ and they are dependent on each other.

Comment: The assumption (not fully justified in real life) that bit errors are *independent* is missing from the problem statement.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that is true. But can we still solve this assuming they are independent?

Comment: I don't see the difference between `p` and `q`

Comment: `p` is the probability that a bit is flipped (error). `q` is the parameter that these errors are distributed over a length of `N` bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the event that the packet is transmitted error-free. The probability that none of $n$ bits is transmitted wrong (assuming errors in different bit positions occur independently), is simply $P(X|N=n)=(1-p)^n$. To obtain $P(X)$, we need to add over all $n$
$$\begin{align} P(X)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X|N=n)P(N=n)\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^n(1-q)^{n-1}q \end{align}$$
which I am sure you can compute using geometric series.

Comment: Perfect! Should have defined X the way you did/was asked for. Thank you!